# How to send Email through PHP without using any additional PEAR package or library?

Tags: php, smtp

I want to send email through PHP without installing or configuring any PHP mail server.what are the ways to achieve this.

Comment: by just putting mail() function

Comment: Can you give me the syntax for that mail function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
```

Remember you cannot send email through localhost. This function will send information when your code is online

Comment: where this mail function is defined should i include or require any additional file where this mail function is defined

Comment: This is a built in function of php. You dont need to define it by yourself. There is no need to define in any other file. just call it at what step do you want to send the email

Comment: Thanks man Although there are other ways to send emails using PHP , but the way u suggested is much more simpler . Thanks a lot.

Comment: when i am sending message using this function i got <br/> tags with text, while i put them to make new line, but i receive them as text.

Comment: Hey this function is sending email in SPAM folder :(

Comment: The number of emails that you sent?

Answer (score 8):

I always use the PHP Mailer class, this class is really easy to use, and so powerful. Give it a try.

You can download it from here [PHP MAILER](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php)

Here's an example

```
    require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

    $body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
    $body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

    $mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

    $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

    $mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

    $address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

    $mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
    $mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {


echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: +1 Ronald for giving a detail answer. But what is different between using a php mailer class and simple mail function?

Comment: @Awais - php mailer made it easier for the coder by calling methods and properties, also embedding images to a mail is so easy.